Grouping the checklist filter items in Sitecore SXA Search
Is there a way in the OOTB SXA search component (like Filter checklist) to have the tags grouped as below?
More like a nested facets.


You can use SxaTags field as a facet for your Filter (Checklist) component and/or other SXA search filter components, see more about component configuration here.
Note that SXA-specific fields are not automatically included in all indexes, so if you want to search content by tags using the SXA search features, you must configure your custom index to include the SXA tags by adding SxaTags field. Read more about SXA tags here.
